# How to make the window (webview) in Chrome Packaged Apps scroll for pages with content more than available height?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-frame

I created a test application using Yeoman/Angular.js and pasted a chunk load of HTML (responsive) to view it as a Chrome Packaged App (CPA). The page_height with all its content is more than the height of packaged application in full_screen mode.

There seems no way to scroll down the view (touch/mouse-drag) to see the content below. How do I add/enable scroll bar on a page? Shouldn't this be by default?

Comment: ha. I'm having a problem where I can't get it to NOT scroll.  I try to set the overflow to hidden, but it still shows scrollbars when the content is larger than the width/height I set. Maybe you can try specifying an exact width/height on your webview (set it to something small) and see if it scrolls.

Comment: In reply to JT703 who is trying to prevent scrolling in the webview, and any later readers trying to do the same, the following worked for me: <style>body {overflow: hidden;}</style>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem. On your css file, add:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more smoothly solution is below:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RSbp/165/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24911864/3370265)