# Chrome (windows) does not hide scrollbar

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have this scrollable div, which (on my Mac in Chrome) hides the scrollbar when I don't scroll. On windows 8 however, it doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox.

Ie doesn't support this too, but I've enabled it using the following CSS:

```
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```

Is there any way to enable this behaviour for Chrome and Firefox

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D8HNM/2/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

maybe you can use something like that?

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y: hidden;

}
body:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4RSbp/165/

Comment: That feels sneaky, but I like it. Did exactly what I wanted it to.

Comment: Could this lead to accessibility problems?

Comment: this will cause problems on mobile devices where hover isn't present.

Answer (score 18):

Scrollbar is hiding on your Mac because this is a system preference (System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars). And unfortunatelly there is no version of `-ms-overflow-style` for Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I came here to find out 

Answer (score 4):

For anyone comming here, if you want to hide scrollbars in a cross-browser cross-system way and keeping the scrollability enabled without visual glitching of mouse over rendering; hiding them behind the limits of your container is a good approach. (Beware, this will be long)

Let's say you have a scrollable container and you want to hide the vertical scrollbar (even the thin transparent one that moderns systems shows). its ID is #scrollable:

```
<html>
[...]
<div id="scrollable">Some Y large content</div>
[...]
</html>
```

To achieve what we want, #scrollable must be contained by a node exclusively for it (a div would work, in this example #scrollable-cover) and we must know #scrollable layout width and height. Lets say it'll be an area of 800px x 900px. So we got:

```
<html>
[...]
<div id="scrollable-cover">
 <div id="scrollable">Some Y large content</div>
</div>
[...]
</html>
```

And its CSS:

```
#scrollable-cover {
 width: 800px;
 height: 900px;
 overflow: hidden
}
#scrollable {
 width: 820px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

With that, #scrollable will be stretched to the height of its inmediate parent (#scrollable-cover) and its large content will render it like an scrollable box, but, since its width is 20px bigger than its parent, which has an 'overflow: hidden' property, the scrollbar will not be shown, because it renders on the 20px hidden at the right of #scrollable.

This lead us to an inconvenient, the content of #scrollable could also be rendering in that hidden 20px width area; to avoid that, there is two methods. **One** is to wrapper all the content of #scrollable in a #scrollable-wrapper with 800px width and auto height:

```
<html>

[...]

<style>
#scrollable-cover {
 width: 800px;
 height: 900px;
 overflow: hidden
}
#scrollable {
 width: 820px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#scrollable-wrapper {
 width: 800px;
 height: auto;
}
</style>

[...]

<div id="scrollable-cover">
 <div id="scrollable">
  <div id="scrollable-wrapper">Some Y large content</div>
 </div>
</div>

[...]

</html>
```

This way all content will be rendered in a 800px width layout inside our scrollable box. But, if you dont want to add another element, you can solve this with the **Second** CSS only option, using box-sizing an a 20px padding at the right:

```
#scrollable-cover {
 width: 800px;
 height: 900px;
 overflow: hidden
}
#scrollable {
 width: 820px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding-right: 20px
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This way, anything rendered inside #scrollable will avoid the 20px hidden area at the right, and 'box-sizing: border-box' will tell the browser to include the 20px of the padding in the total 820px width of #scrollable (otherwise, it'll grow to a computed total of 840px). Check box-sizing compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

And of course, this example could also work with horizontal scrolling, just increasing the height of #scrollable 20px above the height of it's inmediate parent. That's the clue ;)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who got here not because of system preferences, but because scroll bars in general are visible in on Windows Systems in Chrome:

Do not save your css like that:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

but rather

```
overflow: auto;
```

This way it will only show on Windows Chrome Browser if necessary.

found here: [Hide useless scrollbars that show up on Windows only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484742/hide-useless-scrollbars-that-show-up-on-windows-only/35485047#35485047)

Comment: Simple, elegant fix. Best answer here by some distance