# Hide useless scrollbars that show up on Windows only

Tags: html, css, windows, scrollbar

I have a bootstrap dropdown in my navbar that shows a list of notifications. It's pretty standard code, except that I set `max-height: 300px;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` on the `ul` element. When viewed on a Mac in Chrome or Firefox, there are no scrollbars present until the height reaches > 300px and the `ul` overflow scrolls. On Windows (Chrome or IE) though, the vertical scrollbar is always present, which is really annoying. Is there any way to turn off the scrollbar on Windows or hide it until it's actually needed?

Here is the code for the dropdown:

```
<li class="dropdown notifier">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" style="width:initial;">
        <div class="dropdown-link nav-dropdown-link" id="dropdownMenuNotifications" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa" ng-class="unreadNotices > 0 ? 'fa-bell-o red' : 'fa-bell-o'" style="position:absolute;right:5px;"></i>&nbsp;
            <div class="counter" ng-if="unreadNotices > 0">{{unreadNotices}}</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-items dropdown-menu account" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuNotifications">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="title"><span>Notifications</span></a>
            </li>
            <li ng-if="notices.length === 0">
                <a href="#" style="cursor:default;">
                    <div class="notice-text">
                        <span>No notifications at the moment</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat-start="n in notices" ng-if="!n.read">
                <a href="#" class="unread" ng-if="n.action" ng-click="markRead(n, $index);setTab(n.action)">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa" ng-class="n.icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notice-text">
                        <span>{{n.title}}</span>
                        <br />
                        {{n.text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete-notice">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();delete(n, $index)"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="unread" ng-if="!n.action" ng-click="markRead(n, $index)">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa" ng-class="n.icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notice-text">
                        <span>{{n.title}}</span>
                        <br />
                        {{n.text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete-notice">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();delete(n, $index)"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat-end="n in notices" ng-if="n.read">
                <a href="#" ng-if="n.action" ng-click="setTab(n.action)">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa" ng-class="n.icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notice-text">
                        <span>{{n.title}}</span>
                        <br />
                        {{n.text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete-notice">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();delete(n, $index)"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" ng-if="!n.action">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa" ng-class="n.icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notice-text">
                        <span>{{n.title}}</span>
                        <br />
                        {{n.text}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="delete-notice">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();delete(n, $index)"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

And here is the CSS for the dropdown:

```
.notifier {
    &:hover {
        background: initial!important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle {
        .dropdown-link {
            padding: 5px 7px 5px 0px;
            i {
                margin-top: 0;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
        }
        .dropdown-items {
            max-height: 300px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            li {
                font-size: 0.9em;
                a {
                    position: relative;
                    max-width: 300px;
                    white-space: normal;
                    border-bottom: 2px solid #EEE;
                    &.unread {
                        background: rgba(92, 184, 92, 0.07);
                        color: #333;
                    }
                    &.title {
                        text-align: center;
                        background: #FFF;
                        cursor: default;
                        &:hover {
                            background: #FFF;
                        }
                    }
                    &:hover {
                        background: #F7F7F7;
                    }
                    .notice-text {
                        margin-left: 24px;
                        margin-right: 15px;
                        span {
                            font-size: 1.1em;
                            font-weight: 700;
                        }
                    }
                    .delete-notice {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 5px;
                        right: 0;
                        font-size: .9em;
                        &:hover {
                            color: #C9302C;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.counter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #C9302C;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `overflow-y: auto;`?

Comment: `overflow: scroll` will always show a scrollbar even though there is less content when the height or width

Comment: @philu scrollbars are useless when the content is not as tall as the container, as stated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Change your scroll to:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Setting it to `auto` will display the scrollbar if its needed only, while `scroll` suggests there should always be a scrollbar.

You can play around with different `overflow` propertys using [**this example**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=scroll) or read more about it at the [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

–

Although you could consider using the `-ms-overflow-style` property, which you can find in the [**windows dev center**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx):

```
-ms-overflow-style: auto | none | scrollbar | -ms-autohiding-scrollbar
```

Comment: This does not work on Windows. To see it, go to the `this example` link on a Windows machine (tested on Chrome and Edge), and click "auto". Scrollbars are always there.

Comment: Just got this to work (in May 2021): `overflow-y: auto;`  The scroll bars were hidden on Windows Chrome

Comment: This does not work for me because `overflow-y: scroll` works fine for mac os chrome, while it shows a useless scrollbar on windows edge. Setting `overflow-y: auto` removes the scrollbar on windows, but the scrollable behavior is now gone from mac os chrome

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, the scroll bar is not hidden automatically. To show the scroll bar only when needed and when the user hovers the mouse over the element, you can use the css shown in the following snippet:

```css
.myContainer {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.myContainer:hover {
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="myContainer" style="width:150px;height:150px">
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
  <ul>hover me</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This really depended on the resolution for me. I implemented a website on mac and it is the default behaviour in mac to hide the scroll bar but in windows, with lower resolution (1366 x 768), this solution did not work, while in higher resolution (1920 x 1080) it did.